# Saving navigation history

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, history.js

I have a very big problem...
I made a web site using the ajax technology and the d3 js library. 
in practice I have only one html page and using javascript, d3, ajax and java servlet I replace the content of the page at every click. 
now, let me say that I was forced to work as well, was not for me I would never have done so.

The problem is that if I decide, at a certain point of my navigation, to refresh the page or to go backward (with the buttons on the browser) I return to the home page.
How can I do?

Thanks a lot! I hope I explained and sorry for the bad English!!

Comment: can i use this?
https://github.com/balupton/History.js/

Comment: I don't know what should I use to have a navigation history...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I didn't use libraries.
I used the javascript event listeners

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", funcRef, false);
window.addEventListener("load", funcRef, true);
```

in the function funcRef I have this code:

```
if (location.hash === "#login") {
    ShowLoginForm();
}
if (location.hash === "#home") {
    showLayoutHome();
}
```

ecc....
It works!
:)

Answer (score 1):

As Marty already suggested, History.js is wonderful for this.

Alternatively, take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Amplify js has a storage mechanism that can also be used for this but the best solution that will require less wiring/coding is history js.

Comment: I'm using the onhashchange event! It works but it's very longg!